# SQL Grant Execute On Object where do I put GO?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Confused on the location of a `GO` when granting execute permission on a stored procedure to a role

Approach #1:

```
GO
GRANT EXECUTE
    ON OBJECT::[dbo].[StoredProcedure] TO [AppRole]
    AS [dbo];
GO
```

Approach #2:

```
GRANT EXECUTE
    ON OBJECT::[dbo].[StoredProcedure] TO [AppRole]
    AS [dbo];
GO
```

Approach #3:

```
GO
GRANT EXECUTE
    ON OBJECT::[dbo].[StoredProcedure] TO [AppRole]
    AS [dbo];
```

Which is correct? Thanks!

Comment: GO is a batch separator recognized by tools like SQL Server Management Studio. You don't need `GO` if you don't have multiple batches in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your scenario `Go` should be the last command. All `Go` does is signal the code to be processed. So there are scenarios where you might want to put `go` in between sql commands. For example

```
CREATE TABLE ....
GO
UPDATE TABLE ....
GO
```

[MSDN GO Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

If you are appending this to your `CREATE OR ALTER` procedure batch, you definitely need `GO` between the stored procedure body and the `GRANT`.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE StoredProcedure
AS
BEGIN
  ...
END

GO  --this is required to prevent the `GRANT` from being part of the procedure

GRANT EXECUTE
    ON OBJECT::[dbo].[StoredProcedure] TO [AppRole]
    AS [dbo];
```

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback!